# Count total unique number of records based on columns from multiple VCF files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, large-files, vcf-variant-call-format

I have about 200 files having long header lines that starts with "#" and then records with 4 columns like the following:

```
file_1.vcf
##some_comments that span many lines
##some_comments that span many lines
#CRHOM    POS    REF    ALT
chr1   111    A       G
chr2   222    G       T
chrY   99999  A       C

file_2.vcf
##some_comments that span many lines
##some_comments that span many lines
#CRHOM    POS    REF    ALT
chr2   444    G       T
chr2   222    G       T
chrY   7473  C       A
```

For this simple example with only 2 vcf, the expected total number of records is 5 records.

Each of the files contain a million or so records and I am trying to count how many total number of records they are with one condition that a duplicate record appeared in any other vcf file must be counted only once. How can I accomplish this, I attempt this in Python but this stuck for very long time:

```
    import os
    from pathlib import Path
    import vcf

    path_gdc_data = Path(os.getcwd()+"/all_vcfs/")

    non_dup = []
    count += 1
    for i, vcf_file in enumerate(path_gdc_data.rglob("*.vcf")):
        vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(filename=str(vcf_file))
        for rec in vcf_reader:
            if (rec.CHROM,rec.POS, rec.REF, rec.ALT) not in indels_coord_uniq:
                    non_dup_records.append((rec.CHROM, rec.POS))
                    count += 1
    print(f"Total num of non dup in all vcf are {count}")
```

Note1: I include pandas and Dataframe tags in my question to see if pandas would be more efficient solution for this.

Note2: Each individual file can not have duplicated records and each file is sorted.

Sample vcf file:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##fileDate=20090805
##source=myImputationProgramV3.1
##reference=1000GenomesPilot-NCBI36
##phasing=partial
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##INFO=<ID=AA,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Ancestral Allele">
##INFO=<ID=DB,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="dbSNP membership, build 129">
##INFO=<ID=H2,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="HapMap2 membership">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
##FORMAT=<ID=HQ,Number=2,Type=Integer,Description="Haplotype Quality">
#CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO                              FORMAT      NA00001        NA00002        NA00003
20     14370   rs6054257 G      A       29   PASS   NS=3;DP=14;AF=0.5;DB;H2           GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:48:1:51,51 1|0:48:8:51,51 1/1:43:5:.,.
20     17330   .         T      A       3    q10    NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017               GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:49:3:58,50 0|1:3:5:65,3   0/0:41:3
20     1110696 rs6040355 A      G,T     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 1|2:21:6:23,27 2|1:2:0:18,2   2/2:35:4
20     1230237 .         T      .       47   PASS   NS=3;DP=13;AA=T                   GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:54:7:56,60 0|0:48:4:51,51 0/0:61:2
20     1234567 microsat1 GTCT   G,GTACT 50   PASS   NS=3;DP=9;AA=G                    GT:GQ:DP    0/1:35:4       0/2:17:2       1/1:40:3
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the records somehow sorted in the files? Can one file contains duplicates?

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely, I added the answers to your questions in my post, many thanks.

Comment: Can you share some real sample from the two VCF files? the module `vcf` complains the files from the question are invalid.

Comment: I can not share the data I have because they are patient data but I will share with you sample example of vcf from https://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40/

Comment: I used the example found on the page (slightly modified 2 records in one file to obtain 7 unique records)

Comment: There is a mistake in your sample vcf files. First column is not CRHOM but CHROM.

Answer (score 2):

If the vcf files are sorted and no uniques are within one file, you can use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to merge all files together and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group them (I'm supposing we want to count uniques on all columns). Then count number of unique groups. Example

```py
import vcf
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

filelist = ["file_1.vcf", "file_2.vcf"]  # <--- create the list from `glob()` for example
vcfs = [vcf.Reader(filename=f) for f in filelist]

uniq = sum(1 for _ in groupby(merge(*vcfs)))

print("Total number of unique records:", uniq)
```

Prints (in my example case):

```
Total number of unique records: 7
```

---

EDIT: To count uniques only on CHROM, POS, REF, ALT columns:

```py
import vcf
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

filelist = ["file_1.vcf", "file_2.vcf"]
vcfs = [
    ((row.CHROM, row.POS, row.REF, row.ALT) for row in vcf.Reader(filename=f))
    for f in filelist
]

uniq = sum(1 for _ in groupby(merge(*vcfs)))

print("Total number of unique records:", uniq)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the counting for unique only for columns: CHROM POS         REF ALT and not all columns, please see my sample file_1.vcf and file_2.vcf

Comment: Thank you, I got the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of '_Substitution' and '_Substitution'. The error pointing to the line where the uniq variable is created.

Comment: @aBiologist Are you using the exact code? The generators inside list `vcfs` must return tuples of `(CHROM, POS, REF, ALT)`

Comment: Yes I am using the same exact code. The error points to this part here "for _ in groupby(merge(*vcfs)"

Comment: @aBiologist I'm using the exact same code. Maybe a different version of `vcf`? (My `vcf.VERSION == 0.6.8`)

Comment: Same version 0.6.8

Comment: @aBiologist  Try to convert the data to strings, for example `((str(row.CHROM), str(row.POS), str(row.REF), str(row.ALT)) for row in vcf.Reader(filename=f))` ...

Comment: @AndrejKesely. Very smart as usual! +1

Comment: I’ve tried that, it works but when I run the codes on 200 VCF files with about 1 millions records, your code is still running for hours and not yet completed.

Comment: @aBiologist I don't know why `((row.CHROM, row.POS, row.REF, row.ALT) for row in vcf.Reader(filename=f))` isn't working and there needs to be `str()` conversion (the conversions slows things). But 200 * 1million each is LOT of data. Good idea is to integrate `tqdm` module to have progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `Pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
from pathlib import Path

COLS = ["CRHOM", "POS", "REF", "ALT"]

def read_vcf(filepath_or_buffer, usecols=None):
    with open(filepath_or_buffer) as vcf:
        while True:
            line = vcf.readline()
            if not line.startswith("##"):
                names = line[1:].split()
                break
        return pd.read_table(vcf, sep="\t", delim_whitespace=True,
                             usecols=usecols, header=None, names=names)


# Get vcf file list and load the first to a dataframe
path_gdc_data = Path().cwd() / "all_vcfs"
vcf_files = path_gdc_data.glob("*.vcf")
# df = read_vcf(next(vcf_files), usecols=COLS)
idx = read_vcf(next(vcf_files), usecols=COLS).set_index(COLS).index


# Compare and merge other dataframes
for vcf in vcf_files:
    # df1 = read_vcf(vcf, usecols=COLS)
    idx1 = read_vcf(vcf, usecols=COLS).set_index(COLS).index
    # df = df.merge(df1, on=COLS, how="outer")
    idx = idx.union(idx1)

# print(f"Total num of non dup in all vcf are {len(df)}")
print(f"Total num of non dup in all vcf are {len(idx)}")
```

**Example**:

```
file_1.vcf
##some_comments that span many lines
##some_comments that span many lines
#CRHOM    POS    REF    ALT
chr1   111    A       G
chr2   222    G       T
chrY   99999  A       C

file_2.vcf
##some_comments that span many lines
##some_comments that span many lines
#CRHOM    POS    REF    ALT
chr2   444    G       T
chr2   222    G       T
chrY   7473  C       A

file_3.vcf
##some_comments that span many lines
##some_comments that span many lines
#CRHOM    POS    REF    ALT
chr2   444    G       T
chr3   333    G       T
chrY   7473  C       T
```

Apply this modification on the code above and run:

```
26c26
<     df = df.merge(df1, on=COLS, how="outer")
---
>     df = df.merge(df1, on=COLS, how="outer", indicator=f"{vcf.stem}")
```

```py
>>> df
  CRHOM    POS REF ALT      file_2      file_3
0  chr1    111   A   G   left_only   left_only
1  chr2    222   G   T        both   left_only
2  chrY  99999   A   C   left_only   left_only
3  chr2    444   G   T  right_only        both
4  chrY   7473   C   A  right_only   left_only
5  chr3    333   G   T         NaN  right_only
6  chrY   7473   C   T         NaN  right_only
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try my answer, please? I would like to know if using Pandas each time is a good choice. Can you compare to @AndrejKesely's solution?

Comment: I will try it for sure and will let you know how it go. Thanks

Comment: Question please , how merge with outer approach will insure non duplicate data ?

Comment: First and mainly, it's because you have no duplicate entries within one file (Note 2), so I don't need to drop duplicates. Finally, outer merge uses union of keys from the two dataframes: this is a simple one-to-one relation.

Comment: I got it, thank you. You're approach is great but it is also slow as @AndrejKesely's solution, is there way to speed up your approach? I have 200 vcfs with millions records each!

Comment: Easily, no... You can use multiprocessing to increase speed. Maybe you can speed up by using index in place of dataframe. I updated my code. How long does it take for a vcf file to load?

Comment: Ive got problem with matching of the columns. It is not matching correctly, the correct position of the columns get from each vcf is cols = [0, 1, 3, 4]. When I apply this to the code above, it always pick the cols = [0, 1, 2, 3]. I tried both positional and column name way selection of columns but both failed , why is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232489/discussion-between-corralien-and-abiologist).